# Line integral over any enclosed curve attains the same value as long as the set of singularities enclosed is the same?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I get the impression from Laurent expansion that line integral over any enclosed curve attains the same value as long as the set of singularities enclosed is the same.

Is this statement true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by the residue theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem.